# Exercise1.2.18 in Terence Tao's An introduction to measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E\subset\mathbf{R}^n$ be a bounded set.Define the Lebesgue inner measure $m_{\star}(E)$ of $E$ by the formula
$$
m_{\star}(E):= m(A) - m^{\star}(A\backslash E)
$$
for any elementary set A containing E.

(i) Show that this definition is well defined.

(ii) Show that $m_{\star}(E)\leq m^{\star}(E)$, and that euqality holds if and only if E is lebesgue measurable.

I have solved question(i).

But in (ii),when that equality holds, I don't konw how to prove E is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n$ be a sequence of elementary lebesgue measurable sets such that $E_n \rightarrow E$ and $E_{n} \subseteq E_{n+1} \subseteq E$,
Hence for any two elementary sets $A,B$ we have
$$m(A) - m(A \setminus E_n) = m(B) - m(B \setminus E_n)$$

$$ \lim_n m(A) - m(A \setminus E_n) = \lim_n m(B) - m(B \setminus E_n)$$

$$ m(A) - m^*(A \setminus E) = m(B) - m^*(B \setminus E)$$
Hence we have the well definedness of the definition $$m_*(E) = m(A) - m^*(A \setminus E)$$.

We have,
$$m_*(E) = m(A) - m^*(A \setminus E)$$

Let now $E_n$ be such that $E_n \rightarrow E$ and  $E_{n} \supseteq E_{n+1} \supseteq E$
$$m_*(E) = m(E_n) - m^*(E_n \setminus E)$$

$$m_*(E) = \lim_n m(E_n) - m^*(E_n \setminus E)$$

$$m_*(E) =  m^*(E) - \lim_n m^*(E_n \setminus E) \leq m^*(E)$$

Hence $$m_*(E) \leq m^*(E).$$

$m_*(E) = m^*(E)$ $\iff$ $E$ is lebesgue measurable by definition in some texts. If this is not the definition definition you are using then please modify the question with the definition of lebesgue measurable sets you are interested in.

Comment: Really thanks !

Comment: If you are convinced accept my answer by clicking the left of my answer.